# Using wamp server how can I have mysql directory on another location?

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I have wamp installed on my windows and I need to have **whole wamp mysql-server directory files** (and not only database files asked in similar questions) **moved to another location** but after moving when I try to change wamp setting files and config files It fails to run mysql.
I also **tried to reinstall wamp wampmysqld service after moving its location**, But still its failing to run mysql service. Does anybody knows how should I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get 2 different MYSQL Server instances to look at the same databases at the same time?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No I want to use same mysql instance but not in wamps predefined subfolder. I want to have it in some other directory.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Now I updated question regarding to your comment to be more clear. Thanks for the point you mentioned.

Comment: Why do you need the MySQL to run from this `developing` folder. Its a server it can run from anywhere.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Only for a temporary time I need to set wamp settings to load its mysql instance from external location. I understand it's not regular, but it can help me very much to do things on my application much faster.

Comment: Is this other folder on your PC or on a network drive

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you are trying to do this. Someone may come up with an answer then.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's on my PC, I just want to be able to use wamps phpmyadmin area for management of other mysql instance installed on the same computer or change default location of wamps mysql.

Comment: Then leave it where it is. All code that tries to connect to a MYSQL instance will connect to port 3306 by default and does not care where that database server holds it physical databases

Comment: I know that,  but I have changed that default mysql port on my application mysql instance because of it's compatibility with other applications which try to access same port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88715/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-mrez-ir).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we have discussed, you say you have an application that uses a MYSQL database server instance that will be installed with your app. This instance of MYSQL uses a non standard port number so that it will not be interfered with should anybody already have MYSQL instance installed on their sysem or install one after they install you application.

In that case to allow you to use the WAMPServers phpMyAdmin to maintain and manipulate your databases but not have to alter the WAMPServer configuration in any major way, I suggest you look at the config for phpMyAdmin. It is possible to get phpMyAdmin to look at more than one MySQL Server instance by modifying `\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin{version_number}\config.inc.php` to add another Server instance, your apps instance.

So assuming your apps MYSQL Instance is listening on port 8888

change :

```
<?php

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

TO

```
<?php

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * Second server, My Apps instance of MySQL
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql for my APP';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '9999';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

This should now throw a challenge page when you run phpMyAdmin with a dropdown list of MYSQL Instances and a USername and Password field to accept the account and password set for the database instance you choose from the dropdown

Comment: This may not directly answer what I asked but exactly solved my problem as I was searching solution for that.